# Why can't I use WebDriver Wait for Selenium Webdriver for multiple elements in a page?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I am trying to extract some data using **Selenium**, just as follows:

```
elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('busca-left-container'))

for n in range(elements):

year = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ano")))
year = int(year[n].text)
year_list.append(year)
```

The problem I found is that the wait.until function only waits for the first element of the page with the class name ('ano'), so I can't iterate through this WebElement (there are 10 'ano' elements per page)

One solution I found is  using the following code:

```
year = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ano')
year = int(year[n].text)
year_list.append(year)
```

But it doesn't give me the feature of "waiting" until the element is visible.

Is there any solution for that ? (Using Wait function and retrieve a list when all elements has been loaded). 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` which will give list of elements.

```
elements = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('busca-left-container'))

for n in range(elements):

    year = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ano")))
    year = int(year[n].text)
    year_list.append(year)
```